# Sharepoint Online - how can a user with read access request other accesses?

Tags: permissions, access

In Sharepoint Online, a user has "Read" access now needs to request "Contribute" access. The user belongs to a permission group that has "Read" access only. How can this user request more access rights if not knowing who is the site admin/owner?

Read only users do not see "Site Settings" option and there is no "Request Access" feature/button available for them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Out-of-the-box way to request more access.

It up to the owners of the site to implement that, if wanted.